# optimised way to handle n+1 query for non related tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hi I have Two tables User and TempUser tables.

**User** Table has

*id, email, password, etc* fields

**TempUser** table has

id, email, email_status, etc

I need to write a query to select all users from **TempUser** table where email should not be there in **User** table.(please not there is not relationship between two tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TempUser.where("email NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM users) ")
```

Make sure to have both tables have a index on `email` to speed up the query.